# Word Frequency Counter in my code error

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

i need to compute the occurrence frequency of each word in a given document. Occurrence frequency is the number of times a word is found in a
document. my program will take file text as input

The basic functionality of computing word frequencies will be implemented using a linkedlist. Each node in the list contains a word, its frequency and a pointer to the next node. The
basic algorithm is as follows :

If the word is NOT found in the list
Add this word to the list
Set its frequency to 1
Else
Increment the word’s frequency by 1 //As this word already exists in the list

and this is my class : Word

```
public class Word {
    private String word ;
    private int frequency;

    public Word() {

    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }



}
```

and this is Documentword.class

p

```
ublic class DocumentWords {

    private LinkedList<Word> list = new LinkedList<>();
    private Word word = new Word();
    String test = " ";
    Boolean flag = false ;
    int count=0;
    int c ; 

    File document = new File("E:\\Jooo\\Project 2 (All Files)\\Project 2 (All Files)\\aa.txt");

    Scanner sc;

    public DocumentWords() {


        try {
            this.sc = new Scanner(document);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            test = sc.next();
//            System.out.println(test);

            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                word.setWord(test);
                word.setFrequency(1);
                list.add(word);

            } 

              else {

                System.out.println(list.size());

                while(count!=list.size()){

                     if ((list.get(count).getWord()).equals(test)) {
                        flag = true;
                        c=count;

                    }
                     count++;
                }

                if(flag){
                    list.get(c).setFrequency((list.get(c).getFrequency())+1);
                }
                else {
                word.setWord(test);
                        word.setFrequency(1);
                        list.add(word);

                }
            }


        }


            System.out.println("Word : "+ list.get(5).getWord()+"---Freq : "+list.get(5).getFrequency());



    }

}
```

and this code cant run well

Comment: What doesn't run well about the code? Does it perform slow? Does it give you the wrong answer? Does it throw errors? Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: the output is not right it out the last elment of list every time i run it

Comment: Whats the last element that is giving you issues?